# Find intersect values in arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I need to get values that are in all arrays. Example:

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];
$array4 = [];
```

Answer - empty array [].

```
$array1 = [1,3,6,7];
$array2 = [63,34,1,2];
$array3 = [1,7,5,2];
```

Answer - [1]

I can do it with array_intersect() -

```
$result = array_intersect($array1, $array2,  $array3);
```

But I have a big problem - I don't know how many declared  arrays I have (min=0, max=7)

```
$a = rand(true, false);
$b = rand(true, false);
if ($a) {
    $array1 = [1,3,5,7];
}
if ($b) {
    $array2 = [];
}
$array3 = [1,8,99];
```

If I have `$array2` - result will by empty array []. Else - result is [1]. So I need use only declared arrays.

I can find declared arrays next way

```
$all = [
    $array1 ?? null,
    $array2 ?? null,
    $array3 ?? null,
];

foreach ($all as $key => $item) {
    if ($item === null) {
        unset($all[$key]);
    }
}
```

But how can I how now find intersected values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `call_user_func_array` or variadic syntax (since php5.6):

```
array_intersect(...$all);   // since php5.6

call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $all);  // for versions older than php5.6
```